# Issues with text wrapping?

Tags: bootstrap-4

So the text isn't doing what I want it to do. I can't use CSS! 
[image]

Tried different layouts.

```
  <!--Left Row-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <!--Avatar and Name-->
      <div class="card rounded-0" style="border-color:#499C68; border-width:3px;">
      <div class="card p-2 rounded-0 border-0" style="background-color:#499C68;"><h1 class="display-4">FERN</h1></div>
      <img src="https://file.toyhou.se/watermarks/13876914_Mss5VmUzG.png" alt="avatar" width="500">
      </div>

      <div class="p-1"></div>

      <div class="card rounded-0" style="border-color:#499C68; border-width:3px;">
      <div class="card p-2 rounded-0 border-0" style="background-color:#499C68;"><h1 class="display-4 text-center">Fennec | 17 | She/Her</h1></div>
      </div>
    <!--END | Avatar and Name-->

      <div class="p-1"></div>

        <div class="card rounded-0 p-2" style="border-color:#499C68; border-width:3px;">
          text
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
  <!--Images & Text-->

  <div class="col-sm">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="img-fluid"><p class="float-left"></p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
  <!--END | Images & Text-->
```

Instead of the text being in line with the image, it's halfway down it and doesn't wrap right. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `<p class="float-left"></p>` and  try use bootstrap4 adding flexbox like this:

```
<div class="d-flex justfify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="img-fluid"><p class="float-left"></p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
</div>
```